# Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $Φ≤H$ be equipped with a topology. Under which topology on $Φ^*$ is $H^*\ni f\mapsto\left.f\right|_Φ$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces

Let

- $(H,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$ be the norm induced by $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$
- $\Phi$ be a vector subspace of $H$ equipped with a topology $\tau$

> I want to show, that $$\iota^\ast:H^\ast\to\Phi^\ast\;,\;\;\;f\mapsto\left.f\right|_\Phi$$ is continuous.

We can equip $H^\ast$ with the operatornorm $$\left\|f\right\|_{H^\ast}:=\sup_{\left\|x\right\|=1}|f(x)|\;.$$ However, since $\tau$ might not be generated by a norm, I'm not sure which topology I need to consider on $\Phi^\ast$.

> This question is motivated by the [Wikipedia article about the Gelfand triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space#Functional_analysis_approach). They state, that $H^\ast$ is continuously embedded into $\Phi^\ast$.

The answer to this question would be easy, if $\tau$ would be generated by a norm. In that case, we would have $$\left\|\iota^\ast(f)\right\|_{\Phi^\ast}\le\left\|f\right\|_{H^\ast}\tag 1$$ and since $\iota^\ast$ is linear, $(1)$ immediately yields the continuity of $\iota^\ast$.